# Facebook og:image tag could not be downloaded from Drupal website

Tags: drupal, image-processing, facebook-opengraph, plupload, panels

I have a Drupal photography website. Images are important to me and no matter how hard I try, how hard I google, I couldn't get those images to work on Facebook Open Graph sharing.

1. I am using Drupal 7.14.
2. Users upload photos by using Plupload plugin.
3. Over-sized photos are automatically resized by Plupload resize function.
4. These photos are uploaded into a custom-directory. eg. sites/default/files/products/[user:id]/
5. The photos are thumbnailed and styled according to Drupal core styling. eg. sites/default/files/styles/large/
6. These photos are displayed in a overriden node page, which I have customized using Panels.
7. Drupal modules currently don't support Open Graph tags for Panels, so I created them myself using `drupal_add_html_head`.

   // OG Image Tag 
   $node = node_load(%node:nid); 
   $user = $node->uid; 
   $filename = $node->field_product_photos['und'][0]['filename'];
   $base_url = "http://www.[my-web-site].com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/products"; 
   $image_url = $base_url . "/" . $user . "/" . $filename; 
   // Thus $image_url outputs my full image url address. eg. http://www.[my-web-site].com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/products/1/[IMAGE].JPG 
   $element = array ( 
   '#tag' => 'meta',
   '#attributes' => array(
     'property' => 'og:image',
     'content' => $image_url
   ),
   );
   require_once 'includes/common.inc';
   drupal_add_html_head($element, 'og_image');
8. I use http://ogp.spypixel.com/Pogo/checker/index.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.feelsion.com%2Fproduct%2Fd700 to check my OG tags. og:title, og:image, og:url, og:description works like a charm with no problems.
9. However Facebook Debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.feelsion.com%2Fproduct%2Fd700 returns only **ONE** problem.
    That is - **Unable to download og:image:  The image referenced by the url of og:image tag could not be downloaded.**
10. I can confirm that ogp.spypixel.com/Pogo/checker/ could display my og:image and the image url is healthy.
11. I am using HTTP, so HTTPS bug for Facebook og:image is irrelevant.
12. I have ALT-txt for my images.
13. I have also included `<link rel="image_src" href="[IMAGE_LINK]"`into `<HEAD>`.
14. My image sizes fulfills Facebook's criteria. At least 200px for both dimensions and not more than 3:1 by proportion.
15. I have declared og:namespace in my page.tpl.php file.
    xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#
16. No matter how hard I Google and amend the codes and try new images. Facebook still never display my photos and returns the error as in note #9.
17. Image such as my website logo can be displayed in Facebook sharing. The only images not displaying is from the custom node page/panel.
18. I have tried to amend FTP permissions for the images but still failed.
19. I suspect that Plupload plugin is the culprit that the images it resize cannot be rendered by Facebook OG.
20. I also suspect that could be a case-sensitivity issues on the file name or on the extensions of the image.

I have worked more than 24 hours on this problem and hopes are fading. I am still hopeful that I can find my enlightenment on the problem here. Please do assist me if you know the solution or you are experiencing the same problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Please give actual URL so that the problem can be seen live.

Comment: Facebook debugger:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.feelsion.com%2Fproduct%2Fd700

Comment: http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http://www.feelsion.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/products/37/IMG_4549.JPG – __500 Internal Server Error__ – since this does _not_ happen when requesting the image URL with a “normal” browser, your server obviously reacts differently to “bots” trying to get the image – might be because of user agent, cookies, or for some other reason. Up to you to debug this; start with looking in your server logs.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tips. At least I have a new clue to solve it.

Comment: [Sun Jul 08 02:57:54 2012] [alert] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] /home/feelsion/public_html/sites/default/files/.htaccess: **Option FollowSymLinks** not allowed here, referer: http://www.feelsion.com/product/d700
Could this be the root of the problem?

Comment: Looks like. Doesn’t explain though why it doesn’t give the same error when requesting the file with a normal browser. Any rewriting or so in play when the user agent is unknown …?

Comment: CBroe, thank you so much man! You are a genius, by commenting/disabling **Option FollowSymLinks** in the .htaccess file have solved to problem. Images are now appearing in Facebook and there is no more HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. Problem solved. Thank you once again!

Comment: You should check though, if “everything else” still works as expected. _Option FollowSymLinks_ might be necessary for URL rewriting for example (if it is not already set on a higher level).

Comment: Yes Cbroe, everything else is working fine. If there are any problems arise due to this in the future, I will keep everyone updated. Thank you once again Cbroe. You solved my 24 hours problem in 24 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem above occurred because of a **HTTP 500 Internal Server Error** on the image. 
The image appears well with internet browser but is inaccessible by search engine bots.

I have solved the problem by disabling `Option FollowSymLinks` in the .htaccess file in **/public_html/sites/default/files/** folder.

To disable the option permanently, you have to erase the content of the .htaccess file while retaining the file itself in the folder.

Hope that helps, cheers.